# How to put searchbar into header - react-native-elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

i don't know how to put searchbar into header

This is my code

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Header
            centerComponent={<SearchBar></SearchBar>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  } 
}
```

and looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc3lk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the search bar is already inside the header component, but the search bar's size is bigger than the header height. You can check it with the inspect element in the browser. Try to increase the height of the header

You can improve the code like this

```
 <Header centerComponent={<SearchBar/>} />
```